# Test COUNT missing hours and show the results as some sort of array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, testing

I have a set list of PKs that should have 24 hourly records everyday. Some days are missing hours. Is there any way to identify which hours are missing and log them in the results in some sort of array?

Here are the list of available PKs with examples

```
DimGeneratorPK - ex.23,62,63,89
DimDatePK - 20190101, 20190102, 20190103. it is sequential
DimHourPK - 1,2,3,4,5,6....24
DimMonthPK - 20190101, 20190201, 20190501. Only the month value moves, the days are always 01.
```

I can do

```
 select count(DimHourPK)
  from CalcTableExample
  where DimMonthPK = '20190801'
 and DimGeneratorPK = 1619
```

for one generator, and I see 744. That makes sense because August has 31 days * 24 hours in a day. Is it possible to have the results show as an array with all my possible DimGeneratorPKs in one sweep. Then a Temp column that possibly lists some information pertaining to the missing DimHourPKS that are missing from that Month or whatever date range you choose.

Comment: That sample data is very difficult to understand. Sample data is better provided as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements.

Comment: There is no way to log them in "some sort of array" using SQL Server for the simple reason that SQL Server does not support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will give hour per generator and date the missing hours

```
select DimGeneratorPK, DimMonthPK, sum(missingHours), count(*) as CountDaysWithMissingHours
from
(
  select DimMonthPK , DimGeneratorPK , 24 - count(*) as missingHours from 
 CalcTableExample 
 group by DimDatePK , DimGeneratorPK, DimMonthPK 
)a
group by DimGeneratorPK, DimMonthPK
```

Let me know if that works